# is there is any format to design a database in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend

I am new to MongoDB, I am planning to create an e-servicing site that handles large data. It has 6 main categories and its subcategories
eg: main: Dress sub: shirt, pants, t-shirt, inners.
it's just example categories do I need to create a separate database  for every main category and user details , admin, etc. or just one database and add all subcategories in it as a collection,

Comment: There is documentation about [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/data-modeling-introduction/), and more.

Comment: or jump straight into MongoDB University https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M320/about

Answer (score 0):

Actually MongoDB is also a relational database and supports one to many relationship.
So the best way to do this is create separate models for each of your specific data like this:
`` Post.js`, User.js ``.

Then if you want to connect them to each other you populate the database from the other model in the schema like this :

```
author: {
 type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 ref: 'user'
 }
```

So if you want to get data from the user, you populate them like this :

```
Post.findOne().populate('author')
```